# Hiding status bar on MacOS when using Auto Layout

Tags: objective-c, macos, autolayout

I'm looking for a way to hide the status bar of a window while using auto-layout.

Here's the code that handles changing the status bar:

```
- (void)adjustStatusBar
{
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSRect scrollViewRect;
    BOOL statusBar = [defaults boolForKey: TSSTStatusbarVisible];
    if(statusBar)
    {
        scrollViewRect = [[[self window] contentView] frame];
        scrollViewRect = NSMakeRect(NSMinX(scrollViewRect),
                                    NSMinY(scrollViewRect) + 23,
                                    NSWidth(scrollViewRect),
                                    NSHeight(scrollViewRect) - 23);
        [[self window] setContentBorderThickness: 23 forEdge: NSMinYEdge];
        [pageScrollView setFrame: scrollViewRect];
        [progressBar setHidden: NO];
        [self resizeWindow];
    }
    else
    {
        scrollViewRect = [[[self window] contentView] frame];
        [progressBar setHidden: YES];
        [pageScrollView setFrame: scrollViewRect];
        [[self window] setContentBorderThickness: 0 forEdge: NSMinYEdge];
        [self resizeWindow];
    }
}
```

But this is how it looks when the status bar is turned off:

[image: ugly after]

Where the status bar was is still visible. What needs to be done to make the spot where the status bar was disappear?

Comment: Do you mean the chunk of darker grey at the base of the window?

Comment: Yes, I am. I currently have a view there that has a constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `-setFrame` when auto layout is active. Easiest way to do this would be use `NSStackView` with `.detachesHiddenViews = YES`. Now you just hide your statusbar and the stack view takes care of removing it and expanding the scrollview.